# iOS Push Action + Security.framework + Background

Tags: ios, apple-push-notifications, apple-watch

I'm adding a couple of yes/no push actions to my app. Whichever the user chooses, the app sends an API request in the background (`UIUserNotificationActivationModeBackground`) using a token stored in the security framework.

I realized just now that items stored in the security framework aren't accessible unless the user unlocks their phone.

I can set `authenticationRequired = YES`, but it eliminates the simplicity of the yes/no action. <s>And on the watch, it never seems to prompt an unlock anyway, so the app can't dig out a valid API token from Security.</s>

**Is there a good method for accessing secure items in the background?** I'm assuming no.

I'm thinking of instead sending a one-time token with the push payload that's only good for responding yes/no. Essentially avoiding the security framework all together for this particular interaction. **Is that a reasonable approach?**

Thanks!

Comment: Why do you need the token to be stored in the Security.framework? Encryption?

Comment: It's specific to the current user like a password.